# Access any apps bundle identifier

Tags: macos, path, bundle-identifier, nsrunningapplication

For my app, I have the user choose the path for a specific application of their computer. From that path (i.e. /Applications/Itunes.app) I would like to get the bundle identifier, and create an `NSRunningApplication` instance from it (`[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:(nonnull NSString *)];` How would I go about getting this bundle identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the core foundation function [CFBundleGetIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetIdentifier)

Create the bundle reference from the path to the bundle with `CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation` and call `CFBundleCreate`

```
url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundlePath, bundleLength, true);
bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, url);

CFStringRef identifier = CFBundleGetIdentifier(bundle)
```